# Indy TCPServer OnExecute analog of HTTPServer OnCommandGet

Tags: delphi, indy, tcpserver

Is it possible to make my `TCPServer.OnExecute` event behave the same way as `HTTPServer.OnCommandGet` behaves :

```
procedure TMainForm.HttpServerCommandGet(AContext: TIdContext;
  ARequestInfo: TIdHTTPRequestInfo; AResponseInfo: TIdHTTPResponseInfo);
begin
  AResponseInfo.ResponseNo := 200;
  AResponseInfo.ContentType := 'text/plain';
  AResponseInfo.ContentText := 'Hello';
end;
```

I tried this :

```
procedure TMainForm.TCPServerExecute(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('Hello');
end;
```

but it sends 'Hello' to the browser infinite times until I make the server inactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TIdHTTPServer` does not trigger an `OnCommand...` event until it has read a complete HTTP request from the client.

Your `TIdTCPServer` is not reading any requests at all.

`TIdTCPServer.OnExecute` is a looped event.  It is triggered continuously for the lifetime of the connection.  It is the event handler's responsibility to decide what to do on each loop iteration, and provide any necessary reading/writing logic that is appropriate for the communication protocol being implemented.

In your example, all you are doing is writing a line of text on each loop iteration, which is why you are seeing endless lines appear in the browser.  Your event handler logic needs to be more structured than that.  That is what protocols are all about.  And in your case, since you are communicating with a web browser, you need to implement the [HTTP protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) (which is what `TIdHTTPServer` does for you).

Answer (score 1):

The execute method is called in a loop for the duration of the TCP connection. This would be ok for a server push application (except that the message sending should be throttled to avoid overloading the server).

If you want to implement a request/reply protocol, start with a ReadLn (or any other Read method which matches your protocol). This will block execution until the client has sent a request.

Comment: Can you provide an example because `AContext.Connection.IOHandler.ReadLn; AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn('Hello');` sends 7 times 'Hello' to the browser and that's after I make my `TCPServer` inactive.

Comment: If `ReadLn` does not read any data, it will return an empty string. Did you check for this? If it returns an empty string, this means that it timed out before the client has send data. In this case, do not send back a response.

Comment: @Roman_Bezjak: A web browser would communicate with your `TIdTCPServer` using the [HTTP protocol](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616), which contains lines of text in its request headers.  That is why your `ReadLn()` calls are being satisfied, and `OnExecute` would keep looping until there are no more lines to read. So if you are seeing 7 hellos, the browser's request had to have contained 7 lines in its headers.

Comment: @mjn: `ReadLn()` returns a blank line on failure only if it times out, in which case it sets the `ReadLnTimedOut` property to true before exiting. By default, Indy uses infinite timeouts, so you would have had to set the `ReadTimeout` property to something else, or passed a timeout directly to `ReadLn()` as an input parameter.